# Getting Syntax Error Converting from Datetime Character String

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, syntax-error

I have the following code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Main
    Protected WithEvents DataGridView1 As DataGridView
    Dim instForm2 As New Exceptions
    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles startpayrollButton.Click
        Dim ssql As String = "select MAX(payrolldate) AS [payrolldate], " & _
                 "dateadd(s,  518399, max(payrolldate)) AS [Sunday]" & _
                  "from dbo.payroll" & _
                  " where payrollran = 'no'"
        Dim oCmd As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim oDr As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        oCmd = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

        Try
            With oCmd
                .Connection = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=mdr;Data Source=xxxxx;uid=xxxxx;password=xxxxx")
                .Connection.Open()
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = ssql
                oDr = .ExecuteReader()
            End With
            If oDr.Read Then
                payperiodstartdate = oDr.GetDateTime(1)
                payperiodenddate = payperiodstartdate.AddDays(7)
                Dim ButtonDialogResult As DialogResult
                ButtonDialogResult = MessageBox.Show("      The Next Payroll Start Date is: " & payperiodstartdate.ToString() & System.Environment.NewLine & "            Through End Date: " & payperiodenddate.ToString())
                If ButtonDialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                    exceptionsButton.Enabled = True
                    startpayrollButton.Enabled = False
                End If
            End If
            oDr.Close()
            oCmd.Connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            oCmd.Connection.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles exceptionsButton.Click
        Dim connection As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim adapter As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim connectionString As String = "Initial Catalog=mdr;Data Source=xxxxx;uid=xxxxx;password=xxxxx"
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim _sql As String = "SELECT [Exceptions].Employeenumber,[Exceptions].exceptiondate, [Exceptions].starttime, [exceptions].endtime, [Exceptions].code, datediff(minute, starttime, endtime)  as duration into Scratchpad3" & _
        " FROM Employees INNER JOIN Exceptions ON [Exceptions].EmployeeNumber = [Exceptions].Employeenumber" & _
         " where [Exceptions].exceptiondate between @payperiodstartdate and @payperiodenddate" & _
         " GROUP BY [Exceptions].Employeenumber, [Exceptions].Exceptiondate, [Exceptions].starttime, [exceptions].endtime," & _
         " [Exceptions].code, [Exceptions].exceptiondate"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()
        Dim _CMD As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(_sql, connection)
        _CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payperiodstartdate", payperiodstartdate)
        _CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payperiodenddate", payperiodenddate)
        adapter.SelectCommand = _CMD
        Try
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            If ds Is Nothing OrElse ds.Tables.Count = 0 OrElse ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then
                'it's empty
                MessageBox.Show("There was no data for this time period. Press Ok to continue", "No Data")
                connection.Close()
                Exceptions.saveButton.Enabled = False
                Exceptions.Hide()
            Else
                connection.Close()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
            connection.Close()
        End Try
        Exceptions.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub payrollButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles payrollButton.Click
        Payrollfinal.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

and when I run this code, I get the following error

> System.Data.SQLClient.SQLException:
>   Syntax error converting from datetime
>   character string, line 57.

Which is this line:

```
adapter.Fill(ds)
```

When I debug this, I put the line break on that line and look at the Table Value, which shows 0, but I know that there is data for that time frame. Can anyone please assist?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out -- you may have a problem with nullable datetimes:
[Linky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629706/syntax-error-converting-datetime-from-character-string)

Comment: Ok C.Barlow, I looked at that but really don't understand what that means. I'm not really looking to pass null values to my sql table. There is data in my table and when theres not, my form will tell me so.

Comment: Am I missing the point where you assign a value to 'ds'?  I see the dimension:  Dim ds As New DataSet - Then I see you try to Fill the adapter using the dataset, but there's not anything in there yet right?